# Creating interactive PDF form in windws store apps(WinRT)

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, pdf-generation

We want to create interactive PDF form withing our Windows store apps using XAML and C#.

If any 3rd party library is available please let us know.

Vinod

Comment: This question is better suited for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. The SO rules do not allow 3rd party library recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

This topic has been addressed for a while...
I suggest to take a look how to parse the pdf by yourself, or consider using a paid 3rd components....

[how to generate pdf on Windows RT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c.aspx)

cheers!